# Expo error in withDevTools: React.createElement: type is invalid

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm getting this error when trying to start my app in Expo.  My code doesn't appear to be getting hit at all.

```
 ERROR  Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `withDevTools(Anonymous)`.
    in withDevTools(Anonymous)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)
```

Here's my App.tsx file which is minimal:

```js
import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";
import React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Hello world</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

registerRootComponent(App);
```

Answer (score 2):

The default way to create your root component in Expo is by `default export` in App.tsx/App.js - not by using register functions.  This error results when there is no default export in App.tsx.

A correct minimal implementation would be:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Hello world</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```